# C++ Visitor Pattern with variable return types

Tags: c++, templates, virtual-functions, visitor-pattern

I have the following setup:

```cpp
class IVisitor{
public:
    virtual SomeType visit(IVisitable& visitable) = 0;
};

class IVisitable{
public:
    virtual SomeType accept(IVisitor& visitor) = 0;
};

class ConcreteVisitor : public IVisitor{
public:
    SomeType visit(IVisitable& visitable) override {
        return calculateSomeStuff();
    }
};

class ConcertVisitable : public IVisitable{
public:
    SomeType accept(IVisitor& visitor) override {
        return visitor.visit(*this);
    }
};
```

But I want different Visitors to return different types. For this to work, `IVisitable::accept()` should also return different types.

This would result in the following (incorrect) code:

```cpp
template <typename R>
class IVisitor{
public:
    virtual R visit(IVisitable& visitable) = 0;
};

class IVisitable{
public:
    template <typename R>
    virtual R accept(IVisitor<R>& visitor) = 0;
};

class ConcreteVisitorOne : public IVisitor<int>{
public:
    int visit(IVisitable& visitable) override {
        return calculateSomeStuff();
    }
};

class ConcreteVisitorTwo : public IVisitor<bool>{
public:
    bool visit(IVisitable& visitable) override {
        return calculateSomeStuff();
    }
};

class ConcertVisitable : public IVisitable{
public:
    int accept<int>(IVisitor<int>& visitor) override {
        return visitor.visit(*this);
    }
};
```

This, unfortunately, is not possible in C++, as the **virtual** function `IVistitable::accept()` can't be templated.

Does anybody know a way around this limitation?

Comment: Return `std::any`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Several options:

- Don't return anything, handle the value inside the visitor. The visitor is completely free to store or handle any return value and type.
- Return a variadic type (`std::any` or `std::variant`). Note that using them requires you to find out the actual type, which is kind-of similar to your original problem perhaps.
- Inherit multiple `IVisitor<>` interfaces. This might be the easiest way even, although it's not necessary elegant.

Comment: I use and recommend option 1.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. but with option 1 I would also template the IVisitor class, which is not possible, as IVisitable::accept() does not know what template-type it's IVisitor parameter should take.

Comment: @Luke It should not have any parameters either. All parameters are passed to the concrete visitor constructor and are stored there.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. so like this: http://pastie.org/p/02EqtifTZ7JsboB4WZvN7k

Comment: @Luke I don't understand the example. There are no parameters and no constructors. All the work should be done in visit. accept only calls visit and does absolutely nothing else. There should be no casts anywhere.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. I'm sorry, I don't get it. Would you mind to create a minimal example?

Comment: Here's a basic example using a classic GoF visitor pattern https://godbolt.org/z/n9x717o7e Looking at your code I realise that perhaps you have something else in mind, but it is hard to tell what exactly.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to switch to [`std::variant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant) (C++17) instead of double dispatch:

```
int i = std::visit([](auto& v){ return 42;}, some_variant);
bool b = std::visit([](auto& v){ return false;}, some_variant);
```